# how can handle a mouse over a shape?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseover

I have a platform for graph and I'm interested in changing color of nodes (or something like changing opacity for means of focusing on node) while mouse moves over them.

how can I do that?

can anyone help?

this would be a sample node representation in .xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp12
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
            //myEllipse.Fill = nodeColour;
            myEllipse.StrokeThickness = 1;
            myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            myEllipse.Width = 30;
            myEllipse.Height = 30;
            Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, 50);
            Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, 50);
            content.Children.Add(myEllipse);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp12"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example handle the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events:

```
myEllipse.MouseEnter += (s, e) => myEllipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
myEllipse.MouseLeave += (s, e) => myEllipse.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
```

> thanks... actually I have many number of nodes.. how can i assign this method to all of them?

You could hook up the same event handlers to as many elements you want:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
    ...

    myEllipse.MouseEnter += MyEllipse_MouseEnter;
    myEllipse.MouseLeave += MyEllipse_MouseLeave;
}

private void MyEllipse_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
    ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
}

private void MyEllipse_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
    ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: thanks...
actually I have many number of nodes.. how can i assign this method to all of them?

Comment: You could hook up the same event handlers to as many elements you want. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the MVVM pattern, and create a view model with a collection of items that represent your shapes, e.g. Geometries:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Geometry> Shapes { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Geometry>();
}
```

Then display the geometry items in an ItemsControl that has a Path element in its ItemTemplate. The Path's Style declares a Trigger on its `IsMouseOver` property, which sets the `Fill` property.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="AliceBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <Style x:Key="ShapeStyle" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Style="{StaticResource ShapeStyle}" Data="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Initialize the view model like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Shapes.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50, 50), 15, 15));
    vm.Shapes.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(85, 85, 30, 30)));
    vm.Shapes.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(150, 150), 15, 15));

    DataContext = vm;
}
```